# PendingIntent in SmsManager

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, smsmanager

In the messaging program I made, I used **pending intent** to receive the message sending and delivery report. When I send several messages and wait for the delivery report, the program does not recognize which message the received pending intent belongs to.
**My code is:**
`sentSMS = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, msgId(), new Intent(SMS_SENT), 0); deliverSMS = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, msgId(), new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED), 0);` 
According to what I searched for, I have to use the request code parameter for this, for each message I have assigned a request code **(the ID of each message from the database) **in **pending intent**, but I don't know how to receive it in on receive.

thanks

Also i tried this:

```
Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent();
          deliveryIntent.putExtra("id", msgId());
          deliverSMS = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, msgId(), deliveryIntent, 0);
          //************
          Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
         sendIntent.putExtra("id", msgId ());
          sentSMS = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, msgId(), sendIntent, 0);
```

But I did not receive anything in extra

TThanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the `PendingIntent`, you need to specify `PendingIntent.UPDATE_CURRENT` as the last parameter of the `getBroadcast()` call. This will ensure that each `PendingIntent` has the correct "id".

In `onReceive()` you should get the broadcast `Intent` and it should contain the "extra" named "id" with the message ID.

However, if you create the `Intent` without an ACTION and without a component or package name, your `onReceive()` will never get called. Please edit your question and show how you have set up your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right. ButI solved this problem by adding the database id to my pendigintent action name and getting its name and separating the id.

Comment: Is my method optimal and does not create a problem in terms of resources and processing?

Comment: The method you used also works. It is fine. No worries.

Comment: Thank you dear friend, I had a similar problem 7 years ago and you were the only one who solved my problem. Thank you for your reply and I pray that you will always be happy and successful